# How do create a date object using a timezone offset in IE10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a date object using the following string

```
new Date('11/24/2015 17:29 -05:00')
```

However, this is reported as an invalid date in IE10.

UPDATE:

It's the colons that IE doesn't like.  If those are removed, things appear to work

Answer (score 0):

Try an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string ~ `2015-11-24T17:29:00-05:00`